# Why are my dates not sorting correctly?

Tags: mysql, sorting, date

I wonder if anyone has come across this issue before.
I have a string converted to a date and sorted ascending. The date is sorting numerically but it is not sorting on the month. I wonder if anyone has had this issue and can shed some insight as to how to get the date to sort correctly.

```
SELECT
  u.url_id, 
  url, 
  title, 
  description, 
  pub_date, 
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d.%b.%Y') AS pub_date,
  pub_date AS sortdate 
FROM 
  urls AS u, 
  url_associations AS ua 
WHERE
  u.url_id = ua.url_id 
  AND ua.url_category_id=$type
  AND ua.approved = 'Y'
ORDER BY
  sortdate DESC
```

The above is the code and it works but the date isn't sorting eg it sorts like this:

```
 29-may-2009
 28-may-2009
 27-may-2009
 02-june-2009
 01-june-2009
```

Comment: is "pub_date" a string field in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I was a bit confused before. Your original query is somewhat confusing as you're selecting `pub_date` in the list of columns, and then a conversion *also* as `pub_date`. However, you were then sorting by the `pub_date` column (effectively, given `sortdate as pub_date`) - which appears to be a string column.

Your ordering should be on the column *after* conversion to a date, but *before* conversion to a string:

```
SELECT
  u.url_id, 
  url, 
  title, 
  description, 
  pub_date,
  STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS sortdate,
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d.%b.%Y') AS formatted_date
FROM 
  urls AS u, 
  url_associations AS ua 
WHERE
  u.url_id = ua.url_id 
  AND ua.url_category_id=$type
  AND ua.approved = 'Y'
ORDER BY
  sortdate DESC
```

Note that I've renamed the "formatted" version to `formatted_date`. It's not clear whether you still need to select the original `pub_date` or not. It's possible that the `formatted_date` bit could be:

```
DATE_FORMAT(sortdate, '%d.%b.%Y') AS formatted_date
```

but I'm not entirely sure. I'd hope that the query optimizer would figure that out anyway.

Does your `pub_date` column really have to be a string? Why not keep it as a more appropriate type in the database to start with, to avoid all the parsing?

Comment: Thank you, this has worked, I had to alter it slightly by dropping the AS Formatted_date. This is the working code   -   "SELECT  u.url_id,   url,   title,   description,   pub_date,  STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS sortdate,  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d.%b.%Y') FROM   urls AS u,   url_associations AS ua WHERE  u.url_id = ua.url_id   AND ua.url_category_id=$type  AND ua.approved = 'Y'ORDER BY  sortdate DESC";

Comment: Thank you, the date is a javascript drop calendar picker which passes a hidden string to the database. I am now trying to convert the date to a format that an RSS will validate. Thank you so much for your help. I am fairly new to this and the dates have me spinning. Thanks again Jon and everyone who posted, you have all been of great help.

Comment: Then what's the DATE_FORMAT value coming out as (in terms of a column name)? My SQL-fu is fairly weak, but I can't see why it would fail with a name...

Comment: The Date format is passed as a string eg 29-MAY-2009. I have this added to the database in the column pub_date from the JS picker "date". I have it as a string because I honestly couldn't figure a way of passing it as a date to MySQL when I set it up. The extra STR_DATE you have added solved my date sorting error. Thank you.

Comment: This answer gave me the idea I needed to fix a related problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I have had similar issues.  What I have done (and only using ORACLE) is use the date_format in your orderby instead of the already formatted date.

so in your order by use:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y') DESC
```

or - which will first order by year

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%Y-%b-%d') DESC
```

Comment: That's still going to be sorting by a *string* instead of by a *date* though, isn't it?

Comment: unfortunately, I only have access to ORACLE today so I can't verify, however, in ORACLE I just tested and it works properly with the to_char (created_dt, 'dd/MON/yyyy'), which also returns a string.  The limitation is it does the days, then months.  You could always break it out even further with an additional date_format string in the order by to futher order the months

Comment: or you could even switch your order by to year/month/day order by the year first.

Comment: ... or you could just get it to order by date rather than a string field, couldn't you? :) That's my plan, anyway...

Comment: Jon, absolutely, I would normally order by a date which would be the best solution in my opinion and why I +1 your response.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "pub_date" is a string field? If so you would need to convert it to datetime for sorting to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling the query to sort on the converted string, which means that it is doing sorting on a **string** and not a **date**.  Try ordering by pub_date instead.

Comment: Arrgh.  You are correct as always, grand sir.  And you beat me to my revised answer.  I see why there are entire questions devoted to your awesomeness.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305223/jon-skeet-facts

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort like this..

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d.%b.%Y')
```

But if I may, methinks you should consider changing base column from string to date - lots of reasons: scalability, performance, maintainability, data integrity, yada yada yada.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
"SELECT u.url_id, url, title, description, pub_date, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%d.%b.%Y') AS pub_date, pub_date AS sortdate FROM urls AS u, url_associations AS ua WHERE u.url_id = ua.url_id AND ua.url_category_id=$type AND ua.approved = 'Y' ORDER BY pub_date DESC";
```

The problem is you have

```
 pub_date AS sort_date
```

inside the query, and so when you sort by sort_date you sort by the string.
  Replace the sort order by

```
ORDER BY pub_date DESC
```

and everything should work.

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, I am using this current syntax but it won't sort the date month descending.
//"SELECT u.url_id, url, title, description, pub_date, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(pub_date, '%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y.%m.%d') FROM urls AS u, url_associations AS ua WHERE u.url_id = ua.url_id AND ua.url_category_id=$type AND ua.approved = 'Y' ORDER BY pub_date DESC";//
 Thank you for your help

Comment: The problem is that you are now selecting just pub_date, which is a string.  If you use this query, you should ORDER BY u DESC.